# gcc: passing list of preprocessor defines

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a rather long list of preprocessor definitions that I want to make available to several C programs that are compiled with gcc.

Basically I could create a huge list of -DDEF1=1 -DDEF2=2 ... options to pass to gcc, but that would create a huge mess, is hard to use in a versioning-system and may at some time in the future break the command line length limit.

I would like to define my defines in a file.

Basically the -imacros would do what I want except that it only passes it to the first source file: (below from the gcc documentation):

> -include file Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file. However, the first directory searched
>   for file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the
>   directory containing the main source file. If not found there, it is
>   searched for in the remainder of the #include "..." search chain as
>   normal. If multiple -include options are given, the files are included
>   in the order they appear on the command line.
>
> -imacros file Exactly like -include, except that any output produced by scanning file is thrown away. Macros it defines remain defined.
>   This allows you to acquire all the macros from a header without also
>   processing its declarations. All files specified by -imacros are
>   processed before all files specified by -include.

I need to have the definitions available in all source files, not just the first one.

Comment: Have you verified that you really read the docs correctly? In my understanding, _"the primary source file"_ does not necessarily mean that it will only work with the first source file or only with a single file, but rather the author only wanted to differentiate between the the source file(s) and the file that you load with `-include` or `-imacros`. Quite possibly the author simply assumed the "easy" case where there is just one source file, so he didn't want to make the wording too complicated and ambiguous. I would just try if this works, very possibly it does.

Comment: I just tried, it works fine indeed (using GCC-MinGW 4.7.1). Compiling **two** files, both of which use a macro, and including it via `-imacros` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the bottom of [this reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options).

What you might want is the `@file` option. This option tells GCC to use `file` for command-line options. This file can of course contain preprocessor defines.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly - it sounds like you need to do a bit more in your build environment.

For example, one suggestion is that it sounds like you should create a header file that is included by all your source files and #define all your definitions.

You could also use `-include`, but specify an explicit path - which should be determined in your Makefile/build environment.

The -imacros would work, if your Makefile were building each source file independently, into its own object file (which is typical). Its sounds like you're just throwing all the sources into building a single object.